# how to make an image round in d3.js

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, append

to append an image i use this code

```
       node.append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.img; })
            .attr("x", -25)
            .attr("y", -25)
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 50)
```

i want the image to be round i have tried to use this code

```
   .attr("style", "border-radius: 30px;");
```

but it didn't work.. i also tried this one

```
<style>
   .node image{
      border-color: 2px solid orange;
       border-radius: 25px;
    }

</style>
```

but to no avail.
.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use patterns.

1. Create patterns containing the images you want to use in a `<defs>` tag.
2. Use a circle
3. Set circle fill to one of the patterns you created.

eg.:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs")

var catpattern = defs.append("pattern")
                        .attr("id", "catpattern")
                        .attr("height", 1)
                        .attr("width", 1)
                        .attr("x", "0")
                        .attr("y", "0")
```

Adding the image:

```
catpattern.append("image")
     .attr("x", -130)
     .attr("y", -220)
     .attr("height", 640)
     .attr("width", 480)
     .attr("xlink:href", imgurl)
```

And then setting the fill:

```
svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 100)
    .attr("cy", 80)
    .attr("cx", 120)
    .attr("fill", "url(#catpattern)")
```

A JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/wcnxywuy/1/

Comment: You can also use a clipPath to do the reverse, cropping the image to a circle, rather than filling the circle with an image. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fppsru68/1/)

Comment: this is good but the problem is I have a dynamic set of images.

Comment: Can you give an example of what troubles you have?

Comment: This is not a perfect solution. You have to specify the radius of the circle in terms of the picture's size. For example, if you change the circle's radius to 30, you can only see a small portion of cat's eye.

Comment: @LynerKharl can you share how you solved it? I have dynamic images too.